# vba to select specific sheets and save/export each PDF created to diferent folders

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Greetings from Brasil!

I have exhausted my limited knowledge and searched through YT and various foruns without any luck. (Im not a programmer or anything of that sort). Lets see if a willing soul can help me.

I have a workbook with multiple spreadsheets (basically, they are the data source and the other ones price list for various products).  What I`m trying to do is to export each one of them in a PDF format to a diferent folders.  I have managed to export them to a single folder, but this is not ultimately what I want. I need each file to go to a specific folder.  I have also managed to have each PDF filename to end with a "Month/Year" pulled from another spreadsheet source, but it does the job for only one spreasheet, for the other ones, it only renames the Month/Year part, not the whole filename I want.

Help!
here is the source code I am using:

```
Dim fName As String
With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    fName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("G1").Value & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("I1").Value

End With
Worksheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\fred_\" & "TABELA" & Range("L2").Value & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Sheet2").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\John_\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("Sheet3").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Sally_\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I have also tried this code, but I cant figure out how to change coding to save each PDF in various specific folders:

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()
' PDF Export Macro
' C:\*needs to go to diferent folders*
' Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3")).Select

Dim nm As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Variant, sheets_to_select As Variant

sheets_to_select = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

For Each i In sheets_to_select
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:="C:\*diferent folders*\" & "Price List" & i & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4").Value & ".pdf", _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Next i

End Sub
```

What I am doing wrong? BTW, sorry about the rusty english! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to specify the output folder in the FileName argument of the ExportAsFixed statement.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Are you looking at the first code? As you can see,, it has a specific folder for each of the PDF created.  It does the job of saving/exporting each PDF to its folder, but for some reason, the name of the file is the same for all PDFs created, EXCEPT the one in which page I am when I run the macro. I dont know why it doesnt follow on to the other sheets I have.

Answer (score 0):

Use another array for the respective folder names

```vb
Sub ExportToPDFs()
    ' PDF Export Macro
    ' C:\*needs to go to diferent folders*
    ' Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3")).Select
    
    Const ROOT = "C:\temp\so\"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, arName As Variant, arFolder As Variant
    Dim sFolder As String, sFilename As String, sMthYr As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    arName = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    arFolder = Array("FolderA", "FolderB", "FolderC")
    
    sMthYr = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4")
    sMthYr = Replace(sMthYr, "/", "_") ' avoid / in filename

    For i = 0 To UBound(arName)
       
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(arName(i))
        sFolder = ROOT & arFolder(i) & "\"
        sFilename = "Price_List_" & arName(i) & "_" & sMthYr & ".pdf"
        
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
           Filename:=sFolder & sFilename, _
           Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
           IgnorePrintAreas:=False ', OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    Next i
    MsgBox i & " Sheets exported to " & ROOT
End Sub
```